# Is it possible to pass a variable with an & as a parameter in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I would like to pass the & in a value as a parameter.  In the example code below, I can echo FILE_NAME successfully, but how do I pass it as a parameter to the :TEE label?

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET FILE_PATH=C:\TEMP\FILE^&NAME.TXT

REM THIS WORKS
ECHO !FILE_PATH!

REM THIS DOES NOT WORK
CALL :TEE !FILE_PATH!

GOTO :EOF

:TEE
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%Z IN ("%*") DO (
ECHO %%Z
     >  CON ECHO.%%Z
     >> "!LOG_FILE!" ECHO.%%Z
     GOTO :EOF
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
CLS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET FILE_PATH=C:\TEMP\FILE^&NAME.TXT

REM THIS WORKS
ECHO !FILE_PATH!

REM THIS DOES NOT WORK
CALL :TEE "%FILE_PATH%"

GOTO :EOF

:TEE
FOR /F "TOKENS=* USEBACKQ" %%Z IN ('%*') DO (
ECHO %%~Z
     >  CON ECHO.%%~Z
     >> "!LOG_FILE!" ECHO.%%~Z
     GOTO :EOF
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Yes, it is - here's one way

Comment: This works well, however it requires me to always quote all of my parameters to :TEE.  I found that if I change the for loop as follows: `FOR /F "TOKENS=* USEBACKQ" %%Z IN ('%*') DO (...)` then I could pass in values to :TEE without quotes and also quote problem values.  When I quote problem parameter values however, I am left with the quotes in the quoted echo'ed text.  Is there some way to logically strip the leading and trailing " in the quoted parameters in :TEE?

Comment: The alternative you proposed works, but causes me other issues with embedded quotes.  The best solution was your original code sample, which I have tweaked in your answer..